# Django: My views will not render a template

Tags: django, orm, django-forms, django-views, backend

I have the first view, index() that renders index.html
The second vies, success() that renders success.html.

When the form is submitted that points to the url running the view success(), nothing happens- it just takes in the form data and refreshes the index.html

Why is it doing this? What should I change?
The code for it reads:

```
def success(request):
 #the rest of the code here
 return render(request, 'success.html')
```

The url reads:
    url(r'^success', views.success)

Both of these perfectly mirror the index() view and default route, but for some reason this one isn't working.

The form tag says:

```
<form action="/success" method="post">
```

I tried without the slash too. Nothing in the console (message should appear if it has run the view)

Comment: The error is in your urls.py. Post your whole `urls.py` files (both the one for the project and the app)

Comment: Just Got it! The error turned out to be the incorrect regex in the urls.py.